# Possible to use "screen" over SSH in script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, centos, freebsd

I am having this interesting problem, where I would like to start this command

```
nc -l 8023 | zfs receive tank3/pro1
```

on a remote host `10.10.10.11`.

If I run

```
ssh -n 10.10.10.11 'nohup nc -l 8023 | zfs receive tank3/pro1 &'
```

from inside a script, then it doesn't continue in the script, because `zfs` it is waiting for STDIN.

If I redirect STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR

```
ssh -n 10.10.10.11 'nohup nc -l 8023 | zfs receive tank3/pro1 &> /dev/null < /dev/null &'
```

then the script continues, but redirecting STDIN destroys the `zfs` command.

**Question**

Can `screen` be used to solve this?

Or other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try following example:

```
ssh -t root@server1 screen "tail -f /var/log/messages"
```

> `-t`  Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute
>   arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very
>   useful

Comment: It starts `tail` on the remote host in screen, but doesn't give me the shell back on the local host, so my script can continue.

Comment: That's because `tail -f` doesn't exit; it follows the file forever, until you explicitly kill it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have ZFS, but I made a simple script to mimic reading stdin.  Seems to work for me

~/sand/readme.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read X
do
   echo $X
done
```

And then:

```
ssh localhost "nc -l 8023 | ~/sand/readme.sh &\\disown"
```

Or with single quotes:

```
ssh localhost 'nc -l 8023 | ~/sand/readme.sh &\disown'
```

`\` separates multiple remote ssh commands, or at least seems to behave this way for me :). `disown` will allow you to break from a backgrounded job.  I use this whenever I run a long command and realize only after I should have done it in a screen. `CTRL+Z; bg; disown` if you ever find yourselves in that scenario.  You can logout of SSH and it will continue to run in background.

Comment: Very interesting command! It works with your example, but not with `zfs` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use screen for this, with `-d -m` to start in detached mode:

```
ssh 10.10.10.11 screen -d -m 'nc -l 8023 | zfs receive tank3/pro1'
```